# Finding discrete logic levels in a waveform

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, signal-processing

I have some waveforms that I'm trying to process with Python. I would like to find discrete logic levels that these signals are displaying. I have a 1D array of each waveform's x and y values.

The data looks something like this example staircase:

[image: example]

How can I find the different levels? Here they might be around (1.8, 3.3), (2.1, 3.0), (2.7, 2.6) and so on.

I have tried following the approach discussed in [this similar question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/36309/how-do-i-find-peaks-in-a-dataset) relating to R. I implemented a LOWESS smoother (which is the curve you see) with a tight fit to eliminate noise, since the real waveforms have a non-trivial noise component, and then tried doing a rolling max with a window over the data, but I can't get anything solid.

Comment: I'll go ahead and remove the R tag, as it is not relevant to your programming problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your simple example, you can just define a skip size and plot a step function,

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.signal import argrelmin, argrelmax

#Generate some example signal
res = 1000
x = np.linspace(0,2*np.pi,res)
y = np.sin(x)
plt.plot(x,y)

#Take a number of discrete steps
Nsteps = 10
skip = x.shape[0]/Nsteps
xstep = x[::skip]; ystep = y[::skip]
plt.plot(xstep,ystep,'o')

#Plot the step graph
plt.step(xstep, ystep)

#Get max and min (only 2 in this simple case)
plt.plot(x[argrelmax(y)[0]],y[argrelmax(y)[0]],'ro')
plt.plot(x[argrelmin(y)[0]],y[argrelmin(y)[0]],'ro')
plt.show()
```

which gives

[image]

For the more complicated solution in the link, I think this will involve building up the ystep by looking for local min/max in a given range, something like:

```
ystep =[]
for rec in range(0,x.shape[0],skip):
    ystep.append(y[argrelmax(y[rec:rec+skip])[0]])
```

EDIT: complete example giving local min/max for a range

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.signal import argrelmin, argrelmax

#Generate some example signal
res = 1000
x = np.linspace(0,2*np.pi,res)
y = np.sin(x)
plt.plot(x,y)

#Take a number of discrete steps
Nsteps = 10
skip = x.shape[0]/Nsteps

#Get local minimum and maximum in blocks for whole set of data
xstep = []; ystep =[]
for rec in range(0,x.shape[0],skip):
    srt = rec
    end = rec+skip-1
    if (y[srt] > y[end]):
        indx = argrelmax(y[srt:end],mode='wrap')[0]
    elif (y[srt] < y[end]):
        indx = argrelmin(y[srt:end],mode='wrap')[0]

    xstep.append(x[srt+indx])
    ystep.append(y[srt+indx])

#Plot location of min/max
plt.plot(xstep,ystep,'o')

#Plot the step graph
plt.step(xstep, ystep)

plt.show()
```

Comment: I like the full Edit implementation. I see using this with a rolling window across the function with a Nsteps = 1 to keep adjusting that single max, and returning each value that makes a significant jump, 

So in this way if there is a multilevel signal, you could find the multiple maxes/levels that are represented.

Comment: Yeah, sorry I rushed the original answer and don't think this would be enough for the more complex cases in your `R` link. You need `mode="wrap"` so it assumes a periodic signal and find the range's exterme at either end. If there is more than one min/max you may also need to change this a little as `indx` will be an array. You may be able to use `argrelextrema` to avoid the `if` statements too.

Comment: Basically I wanted to find the discrete levels of a multi-level signal without having to hard code the amount of levels to look for. I think I can do this here if I find a max within a window, then increment that window with minimal overlap and look for another max.